# Client Server program in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am new in Qt, I want to write a simple client server program that client send a message to server and server get it and send it back to client.I wrote the server program but i have problem in client and I don't know how should I write it. could you please help me?
Here is my client code:

```
#include "myclient.h"
#include "QTcpsocket"
#include "QTcpServer"
#include "mainwindow.h"


Client::Client(QObject* parent): QObject(parent)
{

 connect(&client, SIGNAL(connected()),this, SLOT(sendData()),Qt::DirectConnection);

}


void myclient::attemptConnection()
{

    connect(QTcpSocket, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(connectionAccepted()));

       if(QTcpSocket->listen("127.0.0.1",1234))
       {
           qDebug() << "Server listening";
       }
       else
       {
           qDebug() << "Couldn't listen to port" << server->serverPort() << ":" << server->errorString();
       }

}

void myclient::connect()
{

    QTcpSocket->connectToHost(LocalHost,1234,QIODevice::ReadWrite);

       if(QTcpSocket->waitForConnected())
           {
               QString string = "Hello";
               QByteArray array;
               array.append(string);
               qDebug()<<QTcpSocket->write(array);
           }
        else
           {
               qDebug() << "couldn't connect";
           }

  }

QTcpSocket socket;

void myclient::connectionAccepted()
{
          qDebug()<<"Connected";


    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readSocket()));
}

void myclient::readSocket()
{
    qDebug()<<socket->readBufferSize();
    QByteArray = socket->readAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You Should take A look at the Forutne Client Example From [Qt Docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneclient-example.html), And base your code on it.

In your code you are using Both Blocking Functions from the waitFor*(), And Non-Blocking signals/slots (readyRead() signal), The Non-Blocking approach is Highly recommended (especially if the code is executed in the GUI thread).

Also I am not sure about your function attemptConnection, which uses newConnection() signal, new Connection is not even a member of QTcpSocket.